# Examine the integral for uniform convergence $\int_{1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\alpha }e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Examine the integral for uniform convergence
$$\int_{1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\alpha }e^{-\alpha x^2}dx, \; E=[0,+\infty )$$

Note that $|\sqrt{\alpha}e^{-\alpha x^2}| \leq \sqrt{\alpha}e^{-\alpha x}$ for all $x \geq 1$. So we can choose a function $g(x) = \sqrt{\alpha}e^{-\alpha x}$, that is

$$\int_{1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\alpha }e^{-\alpha x^2}dx\leq \int_{1}^{\infty }\sqrt{\alpha }e^{-\alpha x}dx=\frac{e^{-\alpha }}{\sqrt{\alpha }}<\infty $$

Did I estimate the integral correctly? It turns out that the integral is uniformly convergent on this set?

Comment: If you are using Weierstrass's criterion, the function $F$ you choose, s.t.  $|f(\alpha,x)|\le F(x)$ $\forall\alpha\forall x$ and $\int_0^{+\infty} F(x)dx<+\infty$ should *not* contain $\alpha$.

Comment: Try to change variables with $y = \sqrt{\alpha}x$.

Comment: @Cactus I doubt if you can use change of variable when judging uniform convergence.

Comment: does the integral satisfy the condition for uniform convergence on the given interval?

Answer (score 2):

The integral in question is:

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x^2} \, dx
$$

over the interval $E = [0, +\infty)$.

To determine the uniform convergence, we need to find a function $F(x)$ that satisfies $|\sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x^2}| \leq F(x)$ for all $x$ and ${\alpha}$, and such that the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} F(x) \, dx$ converges.

In this case, we can choose $F(x) = \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x}$ as a potential candidate. Then, we can see that $|\sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x^2}| \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x} = F(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$ and $\alpha > 0$.

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x} \, dx
$$

By evaluating this integral, we get:

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x} \, dx = \frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}
$$

Since this integral depends on the parameter ${\alpha}$, and it converges as ${\alpha}$ approaches infinity, we conclude that the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x^2} \, dx$ does converge uniformly on the interval $E = [0, +\infty)$. This is a right assessment.

But suppose we make the change of variables $y = \sqrt{\alpha}x$. The integral becomes:

$$
\int_{\sqrt{\alpha}}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} \, dy
$$

Evaluating this integral:

$$
\int_{\sqrt{\alpha}}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} \, dy = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \left(1 - \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\alpha}\right)\right)
$$

Therefore, the result is the the same.

$\int_{\sqrt{\alpha}}^{\infty} e^{-y^2} \, dy $ does converge uniformly on the interval $E = [0, +\infty)$. Since the result depends on the parameter ${\alpha}$, and $\text{erf}(\sqrt{\alpha})$ approaches 0 as ${\alpha}$ approaches infinity, the integral converges to zero.

As mentioned by the OP $\lim_{a\to \infty }\frac{e^{-a}}{\sqrt{a}}=0<\infty$ which is correct. However, I did say that my previous assessment is also correct which I didn't elaborate on why? This conclusion is based on the fact that the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\alpha} \, e^{-\alpha x} \, dx$ converges as ${\alpha}$ approaches infinity: $\frac{e^{-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$ for $Re({\alpha})>0$.

Comment: We say that if $a$ tends to infinity, the integral diverges, but why so if
$\lim_{a\to \infty }\frac{e^{-a}}{\sqrt{a}}=0<\infty $

Comment: Oh. It approaches to zero. I prematurely said it diverges without putting my final assessment using Wolfram. Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: Will you correct the decision?

Comment: It's now corrected.